# How to solve issue "Could not establish TCP connection to any of the configured hosts"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm new in programming and I'm trying to set relationships between my rails apps. I'm using docker-compose and rabbitmq. Here is my code:

some code in controller in Rails app

```
def some_method
  connection = Bunny.new(
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5672,
    vhost: '/',
    user: 'guest',
    password: 'guest')
  connection.start
  channel = connection.create_channel
  queue = channel.queue('hello')
  channel.default_exchange.publish('Hello World!', routing_key: queue.name)
  puts " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'"
  connection.close
end
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services: 
  db:
    image: postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: root
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
   
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s webrick -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/lab2_app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

docker-compose.yml for rabbitmq:

```
version: '3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
```

I can use RabbitMQ Management in my browser and I can send request via curl:
curl http://localhost:15672 => AMQP

But I have error "Could not establish TCP connection to any of the configured hosts" when I call my "some_method.

I was wondering if somebody could help me  :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know when You run it in container Rabbit instance isn't local for rails instead of 'localhost' You should use 'rabbitmq'

Comment: I've changed host: 'localhost' -> host: 'rabbitmq' but it still doesn't work =( Have I done it right?

Comment: If You haven't solve Your problem try adding 
links:
 - rabbitmq
To your web